# render content block to newsletter body drupal 7 auto

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I would ask about Drupal 7 newsletter,

I need to get latest 3 news (its a content was display in block) and set these news in body field automatically, just when user click add simplenewsletter>>

my question is, for do that 
I must right a php code, or i can find a module, or we have any configuration for do that ?

if you can give me any references link, i will be thanks

thanks all,

***Thanks all, Im found an answer, answer is using this simplenews_content_selection module, its will be resolved a problem, good luck all***

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by newsletter? what is the relation between newsletter and news?

Comment: Hi Aboodred1, 

newsletter is a module in drupal, and its used for send a simple news by email, by adding a content, and news, its an engin in website, used just for published latest event ..

now, i need to know how i can get latest news(event) and set it in newsletter module when add content just ..